# jooq, simpleflatmapper, kotlin mapping

Tags: kotlin, jooq, simpleflatmapper

I’m converting a java project to kotlin but getting an error constructing a data object with the query results. The query is a join with a one to many relationship between Docs and Questions. This works in java but I can’t get it to work with kotlin. I’ve tried providing default values and using the no-args project. Not sure if this is a kotlin, jooq, or simple flat mapper issue.

```
Spring boot: 2.5.4
kotlin: 1.5.31

implementation 'org.simpleflatmapper:sfm-jooq:8.2.3'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'



@Repository
open class DocRepository(private val dslContext: DSLContext) {
    companion object : KLogging()

    private val docMapper = SelectQueryMapperFactory.newInstance().newMapper(
        Doc::class.java
    )

override fun getDocDetails(docId: Int): Doc {
        return docMapper.asList(
            dslContext.select(
                Tables.DOC.DOC_ID,
                Tables.DOC.TITLE,
                Tables.DOC.DESCRIPTION,
                Tables.DOC.QUESTION.QUESTION_ID,
                Tables.DOC.QUESTION.DOC_ID,
                Tables.DOC.QUESTION.QUESTION,
                Tables.DOC.QUESTION.ANSWER
            )
                .from(Tables.DOC).leftJoin(Tables.QUESTION)
                .on(Tables.QUESTION.DOC_ID.eq(Tables.DOC.DOC_ID))
                .where(Tables.DOC.DOC_ID.eq(docId))
        ).stream().findFirst().get()
    }

}




data class Doc(
    var docId: Int? = null,
    val title: String? = "",
    val description: String? = "",
    var questions: List<Question?>? = null,
)


data class Question(
    var questionId: Int? = null,
    var docId: Int? = null,
    var question: String? = "",
    var answer: String? = ""
)



org.jooq.exception.MappingException: No constructor available for class com.test.entity.Doc
at org.simpleflatmapper.jooq.SelectQueryMapper.getMapper(SelectQueryMapper.java:186)
at org.simpleflatmapper.jooq.SelectQueryMapper.asList(SelectQueryMapper.java:46)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but if you add _@NoArgsConstructor_ you also need to add _@AllArgsConstructor_ to the Doc class.

Comment: That's a custom annotation created with the kotlin-noarg project. It doesn't seem to work for this problem. It's not a lombok annotation.

Comment: I just thought that it might be that the NoArgs annotation prevents the implicit constructor which is needed by jooq to be able to create instances of the Doc class.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your SimpleFlatMapper usage, but starting with jOOQ 3.15, there's a better way to nest collections if your underlying SQL database product supports [SQL/JSON or SQL/XML](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-14-released-with-sql-xml-and-sql-json-support/) in some way: Use the [new `MULTISET` (or `MULTISET_AGG`) operator](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/)!

```kotlin
override fun getDocDetails(docId: Int): Doc {
    return dslContext.select(
            DOC.DOC_ID,
            DOC.TITLE,
            DOC.DESCRIPTION,
            multiset(
                select(
                    QUESTION.QUESTION_ID,
                    QUESTION.DOC_ID,
                    QUESTION.QUESTION,
                    QUESTION.ANSWER
                )
                .from(QUESTION)
                .where(QUESTION.DOC_ID.eq(DOC.DOC_ID))
            ).convertFrom { it.map(Records.mapping(::Question)) }
        )
        .from(DOC)
        .where(DOC.DOC_ID.eq(docId))
        .fetchSingle(Records.mapping(::Doc))
    }
}
```

This is all type safe and reflection free.